# How to avoid the - from my data in tcl?

Tags: tcl

i am new to tcl. While i am learning some basic command in tcl, i found this problem that i have no idea to solve it.

For example, i have 2 lines of output with data

```
-

watermelon
```

Acutally what i exactly want is only "watermelon", i don't want the "**-**"

I've tried to use regsub as below but fail to avoid the "**-**" too.

```
regsub -all -nocase "^{-\n}$" $fruits{} fruits
```

I've also tried to use regexp as below to skip it but still doesn't work.

```
if {[regexp -nocase "^{-\n}$" $fruits]} {

    continue    
}
```

Any suggestion/solution might help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
% set fruits {-
watermelon}
-
watermelon
%
% regsub "^-\n" $fruits {} fruits
1
% set fruits
watermelon
%
```

Comment: Thanks bro! i just miss out the \